Regression manhwa in which the female lead returns to the past, when she was a noble, and decides to try to marry the male lead
I don't remember the names of the female lead and male lead, but I remember that the female lead was an old woman working together with the male lead, helping ill people. She returns to the past when she was a noble and decides to try to marry the male lead because, in their first life, they met when they were already old. They were nobles, but there was like a disaster and everyone lost everything. The vibe was comfy and the couple seem to be very lovely. Also, the male lead is a green flag.
Please help me to find this manhwa.

This is likely The Duchess's Secret Boutique. It is licensed by Tapas.

When war tore Rubika from her life and her love, Armand, she thought everything was over... until she wakes up as her 22-year-old self! Though ecstatic at this second chance to reunite with her beloved, she discovers that she must now marry Duke Kleimore due to her conniving relatives' scheme. Unable to avoid the union, Rubika decides to just get the duke to divorce her instead! With a marriage to break up and a war looming in the near future, will Rubika be able to safely meet Armand once more?

The story starts with the elderly protagonist dying as a result of a long ongoing war, together with a similarly aged man that she fell in love with but never confessed her feelings to.
She works as a caretaker in a ruined monastery serving as a makeshift shelter/hospital.

Immediately before dying to her wounds, she confesses to Armand. After dying, she wakes up again as a 22-year old living with her aunt and uncle. They are nobles and act as her guardians.

What doesn't match is the circumstances of the male lead and the marriage. The day she reincarnates, she's informed that the rich Duke Kleimore wants to suddenly marry her, despite this not happening in her first life and never meeting him.
She is opposed to this marriage, as the Duke was responsible for her lover's blindness and the ongoing war that killed many people, including her remaining family. While it is obvious to the readers that this duke is her lover under a different name, he doesn't bother to say this and just throws his money around to force her to marry him.
